# Merging two arrays so that they have the same index number

Tags: php, arrays

Maybe an easy question, but I am having trouble with two arrays. I want each element in the 'test' array to represent an index in the 'foo' array. I hope this makes sense.

```
<?php
$test = array(1=>50,60,70);

$foo = array('age', 'money', 'number');
?>
```

Comment: You mean something like `$result = array_combine($test, $foo);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_array  =   array_combine($test, $foo);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

This gives:

```
Array
(
 [50] => age
 [60] => money
 [70] => number
)
```